# How do I assign column headers for the Android GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing a simple application for Android  in which I am using a `gridview`.

In ASP.NET, we use `header text=""`. How can I assign a header for each column in the `gridview` on the Android platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GridView` does not have columns. It is meant to arrange a flat (without columns) array of items two-dimensionally across the screen. You should use a `TableLayout`, which is intented to lay out columned rows.

When you use a `TableLayout`, you can add a header row as your first row and then add your data rows after that. There isn't a distinction between the two.

Comment: can u send me any link or example how to do please